# Cannot install mysql

Tags: mysql

I can't install mysql to my vps server

I tried:

[dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (dependency problems)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446218/dpkg-error-processing-package-mysql-server-dependency-problems)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068270/apparmor-parser-error-for-mysqld

[cannot open /usr/share/dbconfig-common/internal/mysql: No such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65508723/cannot-open-usr-share-dbconfig-common-internal-mysql-no-such-file)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228827/mysql-error-13-permission-denied

[error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' -- Missing /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq)

Log:

```
pastebin.com/jACQmdqh
```

Server has 10 gb storage and 512mb of ram

Comment: are you using apt-get or yum? which package manager are you using?

Comment: I use apt-get..

Comment: are you using apt-get install mysql and additional packages?

Comment: Did you read the message?  It says that mysql is already up and running.

Comment: It says that its started, but its not, i cant connect to it or restart it: https://pastebin.com/sUjYz2dP

Comment: I also tried to reinstall mysql but i am getting the same error

Comment: also.. ensure that you actually want MySQL and not MariaDB.  If you question my last statement and don't know outright, the history between these two siblings is complicated as they were once the same product.  MariaDB will be pre-installed and tested in your package management system and MySQL will not.  MySQL has paid support and probably a paid team of engineers behind it, MariaDB does not.. if you don't know, you should look into this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message in the logs shows "Failed with result 'oom-kill"

Comment: it says that its started but its not i cant connect to it or restart it

Comment: What error message are you getting when you're trying to restart it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sUjYz2dP

Comment: It looks like you're running out of memory and MySQL is crashing. You have very little memory; consider adding more (at least have 4 GB). Once you do that, make sure the heap sizes under my.cnf make sense.

Comment: Thank you! I upgraded my server and now it works! :)

Comment: Great, best of luck!